# How to ignore certain properties and everything underneath those properties?

Tags: c#, csv, parsing, csvhelper

so I am trying to parse a certain csvfile that is as follows:

```
no header values here


(still no header)

Header1,Header2,Header3 |   Just trying to get these values
1,2,3                   |
4,5,6                   V
_________
(values that I'd like to ignore here)
```

I just recently found out how to skip all the way down to where the header starts by implementing csv.Read().For the values, all I want to get is from where the row Header1 is all the way down to 4.

However, one thing that I am struggling with is I do not know how to ignore the "_____" line and everything underneath it. One thing that I was planning on doing was calling the ignore blank lines option, then set that to "_" to ignore it. Would there be a more efficient way to doing it, like can I say ignore the values if it does not match the header properties and format, and apply that to ignore everything underneath that line?

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code using linq,

```
        var file = File.ReadAllLines(@"Your File Path")
                     .Where(a => !a.Equals(String.Empty))
                     .Select((a, i) => new { Data = a, RowNumber = i })
                     .ToList();
        var ignoreRowNo = file.Where(a => a.Data.Contains("_"))
                            .Select(a => a.RowNumber)
                            .OrderBy(a => a)
                            .Take(1).ToList();
        var result = file.Where(a => a.RowNumber < ignoreRowNo[0])
                       .Select(a => a.Data.Split(','))
                       .ToList();
```

Hope this will help.